# Difference between chaining `test` and using an `if` statement

Tags: bash

Is there a difference between:

```
[ -f $FOO ] && do_something
```

...and:

```
if [ -f $FOO ]; then
  do_something
fi
```

I thought they were equivalent, as `[` is just an alias to `test`, which exits 0 when the condition passes. However, in a script I have written, I'm checking whether some environment variables are set and, if they are not, to bail out. In which case:

```
[ -z "${MY_ENV1+x}" -a -z "${MY_ENV2+x}" ] && fail "Oh no!"
```

...always seems to bail out; even when `$MY_ENV1` and `$MY_ENV2` *are* set. However, the `if` version works correctly:

```
if [ -z "${MY_ENV1+x}" -a -z "${MY_ENV2+x}" ]; then
  fail "Oh no!"
fi
```

...where `fail` is defined as:

```
fail() {
  >&2 echo "$@"
  exit 1
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference in the behaviour when you just use `&& echo` and `then echo` rather than your `fail` function? If not, then I'd suggest removing it to simplify the question.

Comment: That `!` needs to be in single quotes either way, no idea how the code works at all. Unless that's the cause of your actual problem and you're expanding random commands at the end ?

Comment: @hek2mgl It expands history.

Comment: @123 Yes, but nut inside double quotes

Comment: @hek2mgl it does in double quotes...

Comment: Ignore the `!`: This was just a proof-of-concept I wrote up for the question, without remembering about the history expansion... I'll test if there's a difference between `echo` and my `fail` function

Comment: @123 Looks like you are right. While `echo "foo!"` works, `echo "!foo"` does not. Good to know that, but still it is not the problem in this case. I've voted to close this question since it is not reproducible.

Comment: @hek2mgl it expands wherever it is...

Comment: It looks like `set -e` is being used as described by 5gon12eder. That makes sense. Retracted close vote.

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference for your, but `[ -z "${MY_ENV1+x}" ] && [ -z "${MY_ENV2+x}" ]` is recommended over `-a`, due to possible ambiguity.

Comment: Also, if you are using a sufficiently recent version of `bash`, use `[[ ! -v MY_ENV1 || -v MY_ENV2 ]]` instead.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the script and run both versions and show the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot diagnose the source of your problem but answering the question in your title, this is the only difference between `FIRST && SECOND` and `if FIRST; then SECOND; fi` that I know.

If `FIRST` evaluates to true, there is no difference.

If `FIRST` evaluates to false, then the result of the entire expression `FIRST && SECOND` is false. If your shell is has the `-e` flag set, this will cause it to abort. The version using the `if` statement, on the other hand, will never produce any result if `FIRST` evaluates to false so the shell will continue happily even if `-e` is set.

Therefore, I sometimes write the more verbose `if FIRST; then SECOND; fi` if I cannot afford a failure status. This can be important, for example, when writing `Makefile`s or if you make it a general habit to run your scripts with `-e`.

Comment: I have `set -eu -o pipefail` so there's the reason... Thank you :)